# Set X-Cluster-Client-Ip in http request

Tags: php, header

I would like to set a X-Cluster-Client-Ip that I can track if the redirection of a webpage works fine. The goal is, that I set a Client-Ip and get back the url after redirection.

I have following script:

```
function getURL($url){
 $opts = array(
   'http' => array)
    'method' => 'GET',
    //here I do not know...
    'X-Cluster-Client-Ip' => '41.70.128.5'
)
);
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
if($headers !== false && isset($headers['Location'])){
return $headers['Location'];
}
return false;
}
```

Is there a way to solve that without cURL?

Greetings and thanks in advance,
yab